# Configure Tomcat to use a different temp directory for file uploads

Tags: tomcat

My Tomcat instance is sitting on a drive with little remaining space. The application I'm running does move file uploads off the server and into a NAS. During the upload, however, Tomcat keeps this file locally, presumably in the /temp directory.

My server has a second data drive with plenty of space where I'd like to relocate this temp directory to. How can I configure Tomcat so that it uses a temp directory on this other drive, ie. how can I relocate this directory?

**Edit:** I'm running Windows server 2k3. I tried setting the CATALINA_TMPDIR env var, but Tomcat appeared to ignore it.

**Solution:** I'm using the "Monitor Tomcat" application which passes

> -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\some\default\directory

to the JVM. This was overriding the environmental variable I was setting. You can find it under **Java** > **Java Options**

Changing this has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `java.io.tmpdir` in Tomcat is set to `$CATALINA_BASE/temp`. You can change it by setting the `$CATALINA_TMPDIR` environment variable before running `startup.sh` for Tomcat.

From `catalina.sh`:

```
#   CATALINA_TMPDIR (Optional) Directory path location of temporary directory
#                   the JVM should use (java.io.tmpdir).  Defaults to
#                   $CATALINA_BASE/temp.
```

Comment: This appears to only work for *nix systems, because when I tried setting CATALINA_TMPDIR env var in Windows 2k3 and booted up Tomcat, it continued using the default temp folder.

Comment: If you set a system environment variable in Windows, you may need to reboot before it takes effect.

Comment: On Ubuntu you can set the temp directory in `/etc/default/tomcat7`

Answer (score 3):

On windows if you are running Tomcat as a service you likely have a key similar to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\myApplication\Parameters\Java`

Set the string value `options` (double click to open) at the end of existing as:

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\{yourDir}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on UNIX/Linux you can just symlink your temp directory on a first drive to the corresponding directory on a second drive. Maybe not a most elegant solution but it worked for me sometime.